# How to export cluster names and values from Carrot2 workbench?

Tags: carrot2

I just started working with Carrot2 Workbench to perform clustering on search engine results. The visualizations are nice, but I am looking to export the list of clusters and their document counts. In addition, I'd be interested in possibly exporting attributes associated with the clusters such as weights.

I haven't seen anything on the interface on workbench, but is there possibly a way I can use the workbench and then export with an additional code snippet?

Any help is appreciated. I've been searching for awhile and have not seen any answers thus far.

Regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **File -> Save as...** menu option, it will allow you to export the documents, clusters and attributes to XML.